# PuppetDB is not storing reports

Tags: puppet

Puppetdb is reporting no resources or nodes after successful puppet runs:

```
# curl -G 'http://localhost:8080/v3/nodes'
[ ]
```

I have verified that puppet is sending the reports to puppetdb:

```
Feb 26 22:04:41 localhost puppet-master[7059]: 'replace catalog' command for foobar submitted to PuppetDB with UUID e653d50d-bf9f-4668-b2f1-9d70044303c6
```

In the puppetdb logs I see:

```
015-02-26 22:08:39,057 DEBUG [o.a.a.b.r.Queue] com.puppetlabs.puppetdb.commands toPageIn: 3, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 3, dequeueCount: 0
```

So it seems nothing is dequeuing and working with the reports. What is supposed to do this? This was working but I think a recent change to puppetdb-2.2.2 caused my problem.

I have rm -rf KahaDB (and all the other db's as well) with no results. This is on a vagrant that I have destroyed and reupped several times as well with the same no results.

On the puppetdb status page, Enqueueing has a ?. I am not sure what to make of this.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up that threads=0 in the puppetdb config is taken very literally. No workers were available to pop commands off the queue.